# GPO Preferences - Local Admin from Trusted Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I have three domains, DomainA, DomainB, and DomainC. There's two way forest trusts between DomainA-DomainB and DomainA-DomainC with forest wide authentication.

I want to add groups from DomainA to the local admins on DomainB and DomainC using GPO Preferences. In DomainA, when I click on locations to select the user from, it shows all trusted domains as available sources;
[Locations on DomainA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnSlV.png)

But on DomainB and DomainC, it only shows the local domain, like so;
[Locations on DomainB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kCha.png)

I am able to add users from DomainA to AD groups in DomainB and DomainC, but for some reason the GPO is not showing DomainA as an available location.

I've tried validating the trusts, deleting and recreating the trusts, and downloading newer ADMX files, but none of that has worked. DomainB and DomainC were forest/domain functional level of 2K3, I raised them both to 2K8R2 (DomainA's functional level is 2K8R2), but that didn't work either.

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you have so many domains? Is this just for testing purposes?

Your trusts must be wrong, or something went sideways when you raised the forest levels to 2k8r2. I'd check your schema and verify everything is configured correctly. The trust relationship between parent-child domains is automatic when the child is established.

Do you see this happening anywhere outside of GPMC?

Comment: There are a lot of domains because of mergers and such, there's not really anything I am allowed to do about that.  
  
It doesn't happen anywhere else, and it is even more specific than just GPMC. I can add groups from the trusted forests to Security Settings\Restricted Groups, but not Control Panel\Local Users and Groups